# Insert into mysql table if nrecord not existed without using unique

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to insert new record in database if not already present. I know I can do it if I make that column `unique` but cant do this as there are several redundant records already present . So i wish any new record I insert should only be inserted if not already present.

**Sample table for reference**

```
id name

1   a

2   b

3   c
```

Comment: Try a merge statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: You could always search the database first to count how many occurrences, then if the count is 0 then perform the insert.

Comment: @PhilipThomson that sounds like a nice approach Thanks

Comment: No problem & good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before inserting do a select query:

```
Select id from tablename where name = 'a' limit 1;
```

Then check, if the result has rows. If it does not have rows execute the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT **IGNORE** INTO... You can find more info on already accepted answer [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update).

Answer (score 0):

I will use pseudo-code to explain .
Use a select query with a WHERE that gonna select only value/values that is/are equal to the value/values of the input type .
You will have to store the values in variables , one variable for the input type and one variable to store the value for the select query.

Before that don't forget to store variables because  if you do a search it will read the value but not gonna store it and the second reason is it's gonna help you for the if and else if .

Also i will recommend you to see POST method and REQUEST method and logic operators ( ex: && , || , etc ... )

You should use a if and a else if .

The if could be:
 if variable1 = variable 2

echo "Data already exist" ;

end of the if

the else if could be :

Insert query 
end of the else

You should echo the value that you get from the select query just to be sure for your test.